# Sharing a local volume across pods in GKE with autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to share a volume across pods in a node in GKE.

I am using Terraform to provision all of this and using GKE autoscaling but no auto-provsioning.

```
cluster_autoscaling {
    enabled             = false
    autoscaling_profile = var.aggresive_node_autoscale ? "OPTIMIZE_UTILIZATION" : "BALANCED"
  }
```

Which means we will not get new node-pools created by GKE, just new nodes from the existing pools. Right?

My original idea was to attach a volume per node and then share that by creating a persistent volume.

I have failed to mount to such disks, so now I am trying to use the boot disk from the nodes.

From the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#nested_node_config) I understand that we can setup SSD disks as boot disk

```
    disk_size_gb = 256
    disk_type = "pd-ssd"
```

And I want to make this boot disk usable as a [Local Persistent Volume](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/persistent_volume_v1#local)

From what I see, the boot disk have the same name as the node pool, so I can use that to reference them

```
data "google_compute_disk" "gke_boot_disk" {
  name    = google_container_node_pool.cpu_pool_n2_highmem_8.name
  project = local.project_id
  zone    = var.google_zone
}
```

And then how would I actually create the persistent disk?

Should I approach this in a different way? Do you have any recommendations or a good read for how to share a local SSD across pods of a node in GKE?

Thank you.

Comment: any update on this ? please feel free to update the status of question if found it helpful.

Comment: I ended up letting go of this and solved my initial problem with a completely different approach. Thanks for reaching out again, though.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to share a volume across pods in a node in GKE.

You missed the checking concept **K8s** side.

As you are looking for multiple **PODs** to share the volume across nodes you have to go with the **ReadWriteMany** or **ReadOnlyMany**.

> **ReadWriteMany** : The volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes. PersistentVolume resources that are backed by Compute Engine
> persistent disks don't support this access mode.

Read more **AccessMode** : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes

if you don't have a requirement of **ReadWriteMany** and just looking for **ReadOnlyMany** you can use the **Disks**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: PV_NAME
spec:
  storageClassName: "STORAGE_CLASS_NAME"
  capacity:
    storage: DISK_SIZE
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  claimRef:
    namespace: PVC_NAMESPACE
    name: PVC_NAME
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: DISK_ID
    fsType: FS_TYPE
    readOnly: true
```

Ref : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks#pre-existing-persistent-disk

If you are looking for **ReadWriteMany** i think you can't use **Disk** with this **AccessMode**. You have to move to **[Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multishares)**.

Other alternatives are going with the

- **[GlusterFs](https://www.gluster.org/)** or **[Minio](https://min.io/)** which in background uses the **Disks** and give you **NFS** option

With this you can create the **ReadWriteMany** access mode **PV/PVC** and attach that to **deployment**.

Answer (score 1):

> Sharing a local volume across pods in GKE with autoscaling

Sharing a local volume across pods in GKE with auto scaling is impossible as the Autoscaler cluster has some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#limitations) in which Local PersistentVolumes are currently not supported by cluster autoscaler.

If you are using Pods tied to a node lifecycle, make sure to plan accordingly as your workloads may be disrupted during cluster maintenance and node upgrades. If you require persistent storage, consider using [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares) instead.

> How would I actually create the persistent disk and share a local SSD
> across pods?

Local SSDs can be specified as [PersistentVolumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes). A local persistent volume represents a local disk that is attached to a single node. Local persistent volumes allow you to share local SSDs across Pods. The data is still ephemeral. You can create PersistentVolumes from local SSDs by manually creating a PersistentVolume, or by running the local volume static provisioner.

Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd#pv) for creating the PersistentVolume manually for each local SSD on each node in your cluster.

We recommend this approach if any of the following run on your cluster:

- Workloads using StatefulSets and volumeClaimTemplates.
- Workloads that share node pools. Each local SSD can be reserved through a PersistentVolumeClaim, and specific host paths are not encoded directly in the Pod spec.

A GKE node pool can be configured to use local SSD for [ephemeral storage](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd#example_ephemeral), including [emptyDir volumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/local-ssd#emptydir-volume). If you are using GKE with Standard clusters, you can attach local SSDs to nodes when creating node pools. This improves the performance of ephemeral storage for your workloads that use emptyDir volume.